# pre-built ROS packages don't have CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All these pre-built ROS packages like turtlesim and others don't seem to be having CMakeLists.txt file in them unlike the user created packages ( where a workspace is created and the packages are built ) . Is the file deliberately removed in the pre-built ones?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256936/pre-built-ros-packages-don%27t-have-cmakelists.txt?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is the file deliberately removed in the pre-built ones?

No, it's just not included in the list of *installed* artefacts. It's a *build script*, not something you would use / need when you're using the nodes / libraries that the package provides.

Compare it to this: do you ever see a `Makefile` in any of the Debian/Ubuntu packages that you install?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-03-14**:
So it would be included if I want to work with the source code to install ROS?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-14**:
If you `git clone ..` or `svn checkout ..` the sources of the packages it should be included, yes.